# Unit testing functions inside the handle method of custom django-admin command modules

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using a custom management command to run code that is +500 lines and contains multiple function definitions(and executes database queries).

**management/commands/talk.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self):
        def hello():
            print "Hello!"
        def my_god():
            print "OMG!"
        def main():
            hello()
            my_god()
```

I can't access the functions inside the handle method seperately (e.g. by doing `Command().handle.hello()`) in order to unit test them or am I missing a way to do it?

My solution to this is to put all the code under the `handle` method in `management/handle_command.py` and then just import that code and run `main` under `handle` in `management/commands/talk.py`. Then I can just unit test the functions from `management/handle_command.py`.

**Example of a proposed management/commands/talk.py**

```
import my_project.my_app.management.handle_command
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self):
        my_project.my_app.management.handle_command.main()
```

How should I best deal with testing functions inside the `handle` method of a custom django-admin command module?

Comment: Sounds like a good start, once you have unit tests in place then you should be able to refactor it sensibly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part:

#### management/commands/talk.py

You will need to define the functions on the class itself using the `self`

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def hello(self):
        print "Hello!"
    def my_god(self):
        print "OMG!"

    def handle(self):
        # this was def main():
        self.hello()
        self.my_god()
```

Second part:

It's obviously preferable not to have these methods stapled to your `Command` class if you want to use them elsewhere / add them to `unittest`. If you're only ever using them in the `Command` class (other than testing) then your suggested method for testing seems most sensible.

Comment: K, I just find it strange that I haven't encountered the practice I proposed here anywhere else. It's hard to believe I am the only one needing to unit test long management command modules containing multiple functions. Btw, thanks for answering both questions I had.